# Ruby Logical Operators - Elements in one but not both arrays

Tags: ruby, arrays, logical-operators

Let's say I have two arrays:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [1,2]
```

I want a logical operation to perform on both of these arrays that returns the elements that are not in both arrays (i.e. 3). Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Arrays in Ruby very conveniently overload some math and bitwise operators.

Elements that are in `a`, but not in `b`

```
 a - b # [3]
```

Elements that are both in `a` and `b`

```
 a & b # [1, 2]
```

Elements that are in `a` or `b`

```
 a | b # [1, 2, 3]
```

Sum of arrays (concatenation)

```
 a + b # [1, 2, 3, 1, 2]
```

You get the idea.

Comment: a reference to sets may be appropriated: http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html.

Comment: be careful with `a & b`, especially when you got duplicated elements in an array

Answer (score 11):

```
p (a | b) - (a & b) #=> [3]
```

Or use sets

```
require 'set'
a.to_set ^ b
```

Comment: (a | b) - (a & b) is the correct answer. The problem with a - b is that it is order specific. b - a gives a different result of [].

Answer (score 3):

There is a third way of looking at this solution, which directly answers the question and does not require the use of sets:

```
r = (a-b) | (b-a)
```

(a-b) will give you what is in array a but not b:

```
a-b
=> [3]
```

(b-a) will give you what is in array b but not a:

```
b-a 
=> []
```

OR-ing the two array subtractions will give you final result of anything that is not in both arrays:

```
r = ab | ba
=> [3]
```

Another example might make this even more clear:

```
a = [1,2,3]
=> [1, 2, 3] 

b = [2,3,4]
=> [2, 3, 4] 

a-b
=> [1] 

b-a
=> [4] 

r = (a-b) | (b-a)
=> [1, 4]
```